# LINQ-to-object string.Substring not returning results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

So I'm trying to do a simple join on two objects. One of the objects has a column with two chars in and the other I join on I use substring to get the 2 chars I want.

It looks like this:

```
  Dim data As IEnumerable(Of AssignmentsInQCItem)
        Using dbContext = New WebDataEntities()
            Dim inQCRCDs = New String() {"DIR", "IN"}

            data = Await (From m In dbContext.MainDatas
                          Where m.CID = cid AndAlso (m.RCD = "" OrElse m.RCD Is Nothing) AndAlso (dbContext.qcComments.Where(Function(x) x.TransNo = m.TransNo).Any())
                          Join l In dbContext.Lenders
                                 On m.ClientID Equals l.ClientID
                          Select New AssignmentsInQCItem With {
                                 .TransNo = m.TransNo,
                                 .IsRechase = If(m.RechaseON = "R", True, False),
                                 .OrderDate = m.OrderDate,
                                 .DueDate = m.DueDate,
                                 .ClientID = m.ClientID,
                                 .ClientName = l.Name,
                                 .Status = If(inQCRCDs.Contains(m.inQC) = True, "INQC", "Pending"),
                                 .MostRecentComment = m.qcComments.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Comment_Date).FirstOrDefault().Comments
                                 }).ToListAsync()

        End Using

        Using dbAdminDBContext = New DBA_AdminEntities()          
            Return (From d In data   
                    Join c In dbAdminDBContext.tbl_ClientPortal_LU.ToList()
                       On c.ClientID_2Char Equals d.ClientID.Substring(0,2)
                    Select New AssignmentsInQCItem With {
                             .TransNo = d.TransNo,
                             .IsRechase = d.IsRechase,
                             .OrderDate = d.OrderDate,
                             .DueDate = d.DueDate,
                             .ClientID = d.ClientID,
                             .ClientName = d.ClientName,
                             .Status = d.Status,
                             .MostRecentComment = d.MostRecentComment,
                             .ClientType = If(c.AKA = "FC", ClientType.FC, If(c.AKA = "LM", ClientType.LM, ClientType.RPI))
                                 }).ToList()
        End Using
```

However this is returning me 0 results, even though when looked at more thoroughly, the substring returns the correct results.

What's even more confusing is that if I write a simple query in SQL, it works fine:

```
SELECT ClientID from WebData..MainData 
inner join DBA_Admin..tbl_ClientPortal_LU
on SUBSTRING(clientid, 0,3) = ClientID_2Char
where cid = '11R' and (RCD= '' or RCD is null)
```

Example ClientIDs:

MC0099, LM0033, HJ0092

Example ClientID_2Chars:
MC,LM,JH

I'm also a little confused why the SQL substring with with 0,3

Anyway, I know my previous query returns data. But the join doesn't return data.

What's wrong with my code?

EDIT:

Even stranger, this returns data:

```
   Dim db2Chars = dbAdminDBContext.tbl_ClientPortal_LU.Select(Function(x) x.ClientID_2Char).ToList()
    Dim ex2Chars = data.Select(Function(x) x.ClientID.Substring(0, 2)).ToList()
    Dim joi = (From d In db2Chars
               Join e In ex2Chars
                  On d Equals e
               Select d).ToList()
```

Comment: Can you provide us with sample data ? it is hard to recreate with no sample data. Also while debugging can you check the item count in `data`. 

Edit: now i have seen the edit i can be sure that `data` is not empty .

Comment: @NetMage This is the real code. I have managed to figure it out but I have no idea why it works. See my answer

Comment: @Andrew My fault - didn't notice you were in VB! :o

Comment: @NetMage Unfortunately yes I am haha

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim data As IEnumerable(Of AssignmentsInQCItem)
        Using dbContext = New WebDataEntities()
            Dim inQCRCDs = New String() {"DIR", "IN"}

            data = Await (From m In dbContext.MainDatas
                          Where m.CID = cid AndAlso (m.RCD = "" OrElse m.RCD Is Nothing) AndAlso (dbContext.qcComments.Where(Function(x) x.TransNo = m.TransNo).Any())
                          Join l In dbContext.Lenders
                                 On m.ClientID Equals l.ClientID
                          Select New AssignmentsInQCItem With {
                                 .TransNo = m.TransNo,
                                 .IsRechase = If(m.RechaseON = "R", True, False),
                                 .OrderDate = m.OrderDate,
                                 .DueDate = m.DueDate,
                                 .ClientID = m.ClientID,
                                 .ClientName = l.Name,
                                 .Status = If(inQCRCDs.Contains(m.inQC) = True, "INQC", "Pending"),
                                 .MostRecentComment = m.qcComments.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Comment_Date).FirstOrDefault().Comments
                                 }).ToListAsync()
        End Using

        Using dbAdminDBContext = New DBA_AdminEntities() 
            Dim db2Chars = dbAdminDBContext.tbl_ClientPortal_LU.Select(Function(x) New With {x.ClientID_2Char, x.AKA}).ToList()
            Return (From d In data
                    Join c In db2Chars
                    On c.ClientID_2Char Equals d.ClientID.Substring(0, 2)
                    Select New AssignmentsInQCItem With {
                             .TransNo = d.TransNo,
                             .IsRechase = d.IsRechase,
                             .OrderDate = d.OrderDate,
                             .DueDate = d.DueDate,
                             .ClientID = d.ClientID,
                             .ClientName = d.ClientName,
                             .Status = d.Status,
                             .MostRecentComment = d.MostRecentComment,
                             .ClientType = If(c.AKA = ClientType.FC.ToString(), ClientType.FC, If(c.AKA = ClientType.LM.ToString(), ClientType.LM.ToString(), ClientType.RPI))
                                 }).ToList()
        End Using
```

I have no idea why this works but it does. All I did was select the only two columns I need and put them into a previous variable